# Why Does bfgminer Show Mh/s and Gh/s As HashRate Instead Of Kh/s

Tags: bfgminer, hashpower

I have just switched over to mining with bfgminer from cgminer and I noticed that bfgminer displays the hashrate as Mh/s on my running version whereas cgminer displayed it as Kh/s.

My GPU is a R9 280x and the most I could every get out of it using cgminer was about 750 Kh/s.

But now using bfgminer it is saying that I am getting ~1.24 Gh/s but I know this is not possible with this card.

[image: bfgminer hashrate]

On my pool stats this is showing as 674 Kh/s which I think is more accurate consider I have only one GPU card.

Comment: Are you certain it you are telling the card to mine scrypt algorithm? That looks like the hash-rate for dblsha with that card. To make sure it is mining scrypt, make sure you have the argument, "--scrypt" in your starting command.

Comment: The command I enter to start bfgminer is as follows: sudo bfgminer -S opencl:auto --scrypt -o stratum+tcp://mining.usa.hypernova.pw:3333 -u username.worker -p pw -I 13 
-g 2 --thread-concurrency 11200 --gpu-engine 1080 --gpu-memclock 1500 --temp-target 72 --auto-fan 
--gpu-fan 40-80 --temp-cutoff 90 --temp-overheat 85

Comment: Perhaps trying "sudo bfgminer --scrypt -S opencl:auto -o..." might fix the problem, if for some reason it requires the scrypt option at the very beginning. Might be worth a try at least.

Comment: @vnhyp0 I tried running it that way too but there's no difference in the display.  

sudo bfgminer --scrypt -S opencl:auto -o stratum+tcp://mining.usa.hypernova.pw:3333 -u username.worker -p pw -I 13 -g 2 --thread-concurrency 11200 --gpu-engine 1080 --gpu-memclock 1500 --temp-target 72 --auto-fan --gpu-fan 40-80 --temp-cutoff 90 --temp-overheat 85

Comment: I wonder if it must be a BFGMiner bug since it shows proper pool stats for the card, but looks like dblsha algorithm speed.

Comment: This looks like a similar issue logged on the project site in Git: https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/issues/345

Comment: I had the correct configuration but it seems like we have yet another configuration option which only works properly on the command line. That's a bug in my opinion, the same option should not matter if it is passed by command argument or stored for convenience in the configuration file. The same behaviour occurs with the scan option, e.g. scan nonauto will not work in config file (still scans serial ports) but -S noauto works on the command line. Inconsistent - and -- too!